# Standalone ruby script using cheezy/ADB

Tags: android, ruby, adb

I'm trying to use https://github.com/cheezy/ADB
 as described here: https://github.com/cheezy/ADB/wiki/Start-and-Stop-ADB-Service

I've installed gem but I'm unable to use it.

My script.rb file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'ADB'

ADB.start_server
```

and gem list result

```
LOCAL GEMS 

ADB (0.5.6)
bundler (1.11.2)
childprocess (0.5.9)
ffi (1.9.10)
```

Error message:

```
undefined method `start_server' for ADB:Module (NoMethodError)
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the github readme and it said that `ADB` was a mixin. Try

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'ADB'
class ADBClass
    include ADB
end

ADBClass.start_server
```

Should work.